# ArcPy arcpy.gp.ExportMapServerCache invokes error: A secure connection with this site cannot be verified

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-server

What worked last week on many computers no longer works this week. My great ArcPy script gets a users current display extent and invokes **gp.ExportMapServerCache** to copy a web  cache locally. It was working very well across: 10.1 , 10.2 and 10.3 ArcGIS desktop.

When gp.ExportMapServerCache is reached in the script a **dialog box** is produced. The dialog boxes buttons are unresponsive. I can't get any other details about this apparent certificate information.

I don't have any issue adding the service to ArcMap and I can see it's details in the rest. This last week has seen a metric tonne of IT updates roll through. I guess somethings eaten something else.

How should I start diagnosing this?

**Security Alert Dialog:**
[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that this resolved during the last 18 months but, if not, I think it is an example of a question best submitted to your local Esri support.